# Android, how to start separate activity from service without launching the main app activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I have separated activity which is launched from service and is used for collecting results after some event.

Problem is that separated activity is launched and after the selectiong of the result by user is closed using

```
public void closeApp() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    this.finish();
    }
```

Separated activity is closed but "under" this activity is already started main activity of the app and this is not what i want.

I just want to do following:

- Display separated activity,
- Select result,
- Close separated activity

Without starting the main app activity (if user want to see collected result must tap on the app icon).

Here is what i tried:

Manifest:

Main activity:

```
 <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CallPlanner" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Separated activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.result.plugin.ReceiverActivity"   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"  />
```

Separetd activity is stared from the service using these tags:

```
intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

How can i solve it and what is best way how to do it?

Many Thanks for any help.

**EDIT: ADDED ACTIVITY CALLING FROM RECEIVER**

```
    /*
             *  CALL RESULT ACTIVITY IN CASE THAT OUTGOING CALL IS ENDED, NUMBER IS AVAILABLE AND APP IS ACTIVE   
             */
            if (DataHolder.getAction().equals("OUTGOING_CALL") 
                    && !DataHolder.getPhoneNumber().isEmpty()
                    && extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                    && isAppActive == 1) {

                    Log.i("Catched", "Catched");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Catched",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // START ACTIVITY AND PASS PARAMS
                intentOne = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        ReceiverActivity.class);

//                  intentOne = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
//                  CordovaReceiverActivity.class);

                if(intentOne == null) {
                        throw new NullPointerException(
                                " :: intentOne 'param' was null inside method 'onReceive'.");
                    }

                intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                //intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                //intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                //intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);


                /*
                intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                */
                // PASS PARAM TO CALLED ACTIVITY
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("phone_number", DataHolder.getPhoneNumber());
                // Put your id to your next Intent  
                intentOne.putExtras(b); 
                // START ACTIVITY
                context.startActivity(intentOne);
            };
```

Comment: Include the code from your `Service` where you are building up the `Intent` and sending it.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "...Calling from Receiver"?  Is this in a `BroadcastReceiver`?  If so, is it a standalone receiver, or one which was created and registered via your main `Activity`?

Comment: Is it standalone BroadcastReceiver which is defined only in Manifest.XML file. How is it pointing to main Activity?

Comment: There's really no reason it should be based on this description and snippets of code. It's hard to tell without all the code and an exact step by step of producing the behavior.

Comment: I thought that some directives such as android:launchMode or some goog choiced tags could be enough, but i dont know. I can post all code from Manifest and BroadcastReceiver, but there is nothing strange to see i think.

Comment: I suspect what you are seeing isn't that the main activity is being launched, but that it was never closed/dismissed or something else is triggering it to start.  I suggest debugging it further via the debugger and/or logcat to verify the order and lifecycle of things.